# Checking for `driver.findElement(...)` in an IF statement throws `NoSuchElementException`

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting `NoSuchElementException` when running the following code.

```
if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gr2']")).isDisplayed()) {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='balInqTableStep2']/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/input[2]")).click();
}
else {
    test.log(LogStatus.FAIL,"Please configure Gift Slabs for this site. Contact business.");
    test.log(LogStatus.FAIL,"Second time wallet credit is not done");
}
```

Comment: Do you just want us to know this information or there is also a question you want to ask?

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Comment: Instead of go with `absolute xpath`, try to create `relative xpath`, then check the same condition again.

Answer (score 1):

**NoSuchElementException** exception means there is not element present on the page.

**isDisplayed** method assumes that element is already present on the page and so throws you exception when element is not present.

you can either make sure that element is present before calling webdriver method and you can write your own method to handle this for you.

following code snippet might help you

```
public boolean isDisplayed(By identifier){
    boolean isElementDisplayed = false;
    try{
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(identifier);
        isElementDisplayed = element.isDisplayed()
    }catch (NoSuchElementException){
        return false;
    }

    return isElementDisplayed;
}
```

and you can call it like this

```
isDisplayed(By.xpath("//*[@id='gr2']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Always when you call `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gr2']"))` and the element is not present in the DOM, it's gonna throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

There is an alternative to avoid the code throwing the exception, calling the method `findElements`, instead of `findElement`.

E.g.:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='gr2']"));
if(!elements.isEmpty() && elements.get(0).isDisplayed()) {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='balInqTableStep2']/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/input[2]")).click();
}
else {
    test.log(LogStatus.FAIL,"Please configure Gift Slabs for this site. Contact business.");
    test.log(LogStatus.FAIL,"Second time wallet credit is not done");
}
```

Hope it works for you.